# Can't delete a login due to db ownership — but no dbs are owned by this login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server 2014 instance that's installed on an OS that I've migrated from one domain to another. The new domain and user account are from separate forests, but they bear the same descriptive names (e.g. `DOMAIN\User`).

Naturally, I can't log into the database with the old domain account, so I need to delete that. The trouble is that I can't.

I keep getting the error message that the login owns one or more databases. But it's very clear that it doesn't—I've cleared mappings and reassigned `dbo` in all databases.

Yet the error persists. This is very odd.

Is there a way to determine what's preventing me from deleting this login so I can proceed to add the same-named account from the new same-named domain?

**--EDIT--**

Correction: I'd reassigned `dbo` in all databases that displayed a login in the `Login name` field. That field was empty for the two RS databases, incorrectly leading me to believe that they weren't owned by the login that I was trying to delete. The script provided by [@hot2use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/15356/hot2use) did the trick.

Comment: what you are getting error? Could you share that one.

Comment: have you restored a db backup?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan — The error was: `Login 'DOMAIN\User' owns one or more database(s). Change the owner of the database(s) before dropping the login. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15174)`. See my reply to the accepted answer.

Comment: @McNets — Yes. This is a TFS 2015.3 [domain migration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-across-domains) after a successful [hardware migration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-clone-hardware). See my reply to the accepted answer.

Comment: I faced the same issue setting up a test environment for a SSIS project.

Comment: @McNets — Do you recall how you solved it at the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the ownwers of the databases with the following script:

```
SELECT d.name, sl.name
    FROM sys.databases as d JOIN sys.syslogins AS sl 
        ON d.owner_sid = sl.[sid]
```

You might then find out that a database is linked to on of your Windows/AD accounts.

There is a slight difference between a SQL Login (native or Windows account) having the role **db_owner** and an account being the **database owner**.

If you do find a database with an account linked to the Windows/AD account you want to get rid of, then execute the following command while connected to that database:

```
USE <databasename>
GO
sp_changedbowner '<new_account>'
```

> IMHO: Changing the owner to 'sa' is a viable option.

Good luck.

Comment: >>>There is a slight difference between a SQL Login (native or Windows account) having the role db_owner and an account being the database owner.<<< The difference is great, and first of all the OWNER of database is LOGIN, not a USER, whereas db_owner fixed *database* role members are all USERS. When IntelXX understand this, he'll be able to solve his problem. When he said he had reassigned dbo in all databases, he told us about users, but his problem is related to login that owns one or more databases

Comment: Excellent! That script did the trick. It was the RS databases holding up the show. Oddly, when I double-clicked the `dbo` user for each of those the `Login name` field was empty on the `General` tab. I'm not sure why that was the case, but your script managed to flush out the pheasant. Thanks.

Comment: @sepupic — Yes, I understand this, thank you; see my reply to the accepted answer. The problem was that the `Login name` field for the owned databases was empty—before his script, there wasn't any way for me to know that the login owned those dbs.

Comment: You are still missing the point. If you want to see the owner of database using GUI, you needn't any "double click", on what object did you do your click, on db_owner role? That shows nothing because you dropped all users, but instead you shouldn't even open the node "database", you have to see database's properties(right click) and there you'll find the OWNER. The owner is not a way to give permissions as db_owner role does, the OWNER is the only ONE login(while you can have 1000 db_owners) and it is checked while cross db ownership chain is used

Comment: @sepupic — Actually, I'm not missing the point. We're on the same point, merely with two different ways to get there. Expanding into `db\security\users` and double-clicking `dbo` reveals the same info as viewing the owner in the db properties sheet. The problem I was facing was that the `owner` field was empty, so I couldn't see which login was `dbo`. It was unrelated to the `db_owner` role. And, since the problem is fixed, I'm now unable to reproduce the scenario. (p.s. To notify me of any reply, preface it with @InteXX—I only noticed this one by chance.)

Comment: @InteXX You continue to not understand and insist. I just don't know how to explain to you the same again. OWNER OF DATABASE cannot be find in USERS, it's not a user, it's login, and what you did, you was looking for members of db_owner database role, and the owner CANNOT BE FOUND between members od db_owner. Db owner cannot be mapped to database as a user with same name as login, it's just there mapped as dbo, it's the ONLY ONE server principal who can owns the database while you can have many db_owners. DATABASE OWNER <> db_owner's members

Comment: @sepupic — I'm afraid you're mistaken. This has nothing whatsoever to do with the `db_owner` role, and it has everything to do with the database owner. Here: run SSMS. Drill down to `db\security\users` (where `db` is the name of your database). Double-click `dbo` and inspect the 'Login name' field. That's your database owner—the same login that appears on the database's properties sheet. Now run `alter authorization` against the database, specifying a different login. Double-click `dbo` again and you'll see that the `Login name` field now displays the new login. Database owner = `dbo` user.

Comment: This time I see, I never started from user "dbo" to find a login but now I went where you said and find it, thank you :) We are really talking about the same, that is login mapped to dbo, I just misunderstood when you said "dbo user" and now I see you was talking about it from the beginning

Comment: @InteXX, I forget to tag you, esxuse me, I checked it out and you are right, see my post above

Answer (score 1):

You should change the owner of all your databases, for example to "sa" (even if it's disabled it'll work) The command is

```
alter authorization on database::yourDB to sa
```

Comment: Thanks, I did precisely that after I discovered the hidden owner on each of the two offending databases. See my reply to the accepted answer.